# File-Encryption is not working in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I am trying to encrypt a file on my android device. However, on running the code I get a "plugin_not_installed" error.

I have installed cordova-safe plugin using the commands
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-safe
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file-encryption@4

I have checked the plugin in config.xml and in package.json and it is present

```
import { FileEncryption } from '@ionic-native/file-encryption';
constructor(public fileEncryption: FileEncryption){}
this.fileEncryption.encrypt(fileName, AppDefaults.FILEKEY).then(encryptdata=>{
      console.log(encryptdata)
    })
```

I expect that the file should be encrypted but instead I get an error 
Ionic Native: tried calling FileEncryption.encrypt, but the FileEncryption plugin is not installed
plugin_not_installed

Answer (score 0):

**Error :**

- Native: tried calling FileEncryption.encrypt, but the FileEncryption plugin is not installed.
- Install the FileEncryption plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-safe'

**Detail**

This error comes from 'node_modules/@ionic-native/core/decorators/common.js', getPlugin() function can't detect cordova-safe or FileEncryption method, So replace your getPlugin() function to this one

**Solution**

*from*

```
    export function getPlugin(pluginRef) {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        return get(window, pluginRef);
      }
      return null;
   }
```

*To*

```
    export function getPlugin(pluginRef) {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        let data =  get(window, pluginRef);
        let androidAndios = false;
        window.Ionic.platforms.forEach(platform => {
            if(platform == "android" || platform == "ios" || platform == "hybrid" || platform == "mobile" || platform == "mobile"){
                androidAndios = true;
            }
        });
        if(androidAndios){
            if(data.safe){
                if(data.safe['encrypt'] && data.safe['decrypt']){
                    return data.safe;
                }
            }
        }

        return data;
        
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It did not work for me on Ionic 6!